# AnyEvent timer question

Tags: perl, timer, event-handling, anyevent

How could I make "visible" the timer? This example returns (intependent from the sleep-time always) `2` (I expected something similar to the sleep-time).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use AnyEvent;

my $c = 0;
my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $once_per_second = AnyEvent->timer (
    after => 0,
    interval => 1,
    cb => sub {
        $c++;
        $cv->send;
    },
);

sleep 5;

$cv->recv;

say $c;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two problems:

- `sleep 5` doesn't run the event loop.
- Your callback triggers the cond. variable. If, for instance, you removed the `sleep 5` statement, `$c` would only be 1.

Is this what you want?

```
my $c = 0;
my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $once_per_second = AnyEvent->timer(after => 0, interval => 1, cb => sub { $c++ });
my $five_seconds = AnyEvent->timer(after => 5, cb => sub { $cv->send });
$cv->recv;
say $c;
```

Comment: I did not yet understand why with `sleep` I get 2 instead of 1.

Comment: You are getting one callback for the "after => 0" and then one callback for the first interval. Try creating the timer without specifying the "after" and see if $c is 1.

Answer (score 3):

The event loop is not running (well nothing is running) while `sleep` is "active". So no event registered with AnyEvent can be triggered.

**The rule**: If you use `AnyEvent` (or any other ansynchronous framework), never use `sleep`.

See user5402's answer for the correct solution.